# How to repeat the same action for diffrent variables

Tags: php, arrays

```
<!-- language: php -->       
<?php
 // test variables
    $l1 = "http://youtube.com/channel/";
    $l2 = "http://youtube.com/channel/";
    $l3 = "http://youtube.com/channel/";
    $l4 = "http://youtube.com/channel/";
    $fl = "http://youtube.com/channel/";

    //set error false as default
    $error = "false";

    //check if variables are ready for use, if they are, add them to `$l` array
    //I do each check as a seperate line, as it looks cleaner than 1 long if statement.
$l = [];
if(!empty($l1)) $l[] = $l1;
if(!empty($l2)) $l[] = $l2;
if(!empty($l3)) $l[] = $l3;
if(!empty($l4)) $l[] = $l4;
if(!empty($fl)) $l[] = $fl;

foreach($l as $key => $value) {

    //1 line ternary is cleaner than if/else statetmnt
    $errorKey = $key < 9? "0{$key}" : $key;

    //each row by default has no error
    $hasError = 0;

    //check if this a valid url 
    if(!preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $value)) {
        $error = "true";
        $hasError = 1;
    }

    if($hasError) {
        //store error in array, to loop through later
        $errors[] = $errorKey;
    }
}
$search = '?sub_confirmation=1';
$searchUrl = "youtube.com/channel";

if (strpos($l, $searchUrl) !== false && strpos($l, $search) === false) {
    $l =  $value."".$search;
}

if($error == "false") {
    echo $l1;
    echo $l2;
    echo $l3;
    echo $l4;
    echo $fl;
}

// deliver the error message
//Check if $error has been set to true at any point
if($error == "true") {
    //loop through error array, echo error message if $errorNumber matches.
    //at this point we KNOW there was an error at some point, no need to use a switch really
    foreach($errors as $errorNumber) {
        echo "Something went wrong here $errorNumber :o";
    }
}
?>
```

Hello, my problem is at the end of the code where the strpos function is, so basically I want to check every url, once if it contains a certain url, and then add something to the end if it is so. But I don't want to repeat an if statement 4 times($fl variable doesn't has to be checked), I am quite new in all that so I hope somebody can help me, I tought about a switch statement but I guess there is a better way. And if I put it in the foreach aboth, it doesn't applies on the certain variables, only on the value variable.

Comment: The `strpos` part of the code should go into the foreach loop as well. Can you explain a bit more, why you think it doesn't work then?

Comment: I need it be checked and edited for each url, if I use value it only updates value and not the single $l1, $l2 variables, and after all this I will work with these variables again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign `$value` by reference using this foreach header (notice the `&` in front of `$value`):

```php
foreach($l as $key => &$value) {
```

By doing this every change you do to `$value` will also be done to the corresponding value in the `$l` array.

Then at the end of the foreach loop you put this code:

```php
if (strpos($value, $searchUrl) !== false && strpos($value, $search) === false) {
    $value .= $search;
}
```

So your final foreach loop should look like this:

```php
foreach($l as $key => &$value) {

    //1 line ternary is cleaner than if/else statetmnt
    $errorKey = $key < 9? "0{$key}" : $key;

    //each row by default has no error
    $hasError = 0;

    //check if this a valid url 
    if(!preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $value)) {
        $error = "true";
        $hasError = 1;
    }

    if($hasError) {
        //store error in array, to loop through later
        $errors[] = $errorKey;
    }

    $search = '?sub_confirmation=1';
    $searchUrl = "youtube.com/channel";
    if (strpos($value, $searchUrl) !== false && strpos($value, $search) === false) {
        $value .= $search;
    }
}
```

You can read more about using references in foreach loops here: [PHP: foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

**Edit:** 
To apply the changes not only to the elements of the `$l` array, but also to the original variables `$l1`, `$l2` and so on, you should assign the elements to your array as references too:

```php
$l = [];
if(!empty($l1)) $l[] = &$l1;
if(!empty($l2)) $l[] = &$l2;
if(!empty($l3)) $l[] = &$l3;
if(!empty($l4)) $l[] = &$l4;
if(!empty($fl)) $l[] = &$fl;
```

Comment: as I mentioned, I already tried to use it in the foreach but, it doesn't change the single variables like $l1, $l2, $l3, $l4, $fl

Comment: Check the edit of my answer. It should work if you also assign the variables to the array by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think this is a good candidate for moving to a `class`. To be honest I'm not 100% sure what you are doing but will try to convert your code to a class.

```
class L {
    public $raw = null;
    public $modified = null;
    public $error = false;
    // create the class
    public function __construct($data=null) {
        $this->raw = $data;
        // Check the raw passed in data
        if ($data) {
            $this->isUrl();
        }
        // If there was no error, check the data
        if (! $this->error) {
            $this->search();
        }
    }
    // Do something ?
    public function debug() {
         echo '<pre>';
         var_dump($this);
         echo '</pre>';
    }
    public function getData() {
        return ($this->modified) ? : $this->raw;
    }
    private function isUrl() {
        $this->error = (! preg_match('|^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i', $this->raw)); 
    }
    // Should a failed search also be an error?
    private function search() {
        if ($this->raw) {
            if ( (strpos($this->raw, "youtube.com/channel") !== false) &&
                 (strpos($this->raw, "?sub_confirmation=1") === false) ) {
                $this->modified = $this->raw ."?sub_confirmation=1";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Test data
$testList[] = "test fail";
$testList[] = "https://youtube.com/searchFail";
$testList[] = "https://youtube.com/channel/success";
$testList[] = "https://youtube.com/channel/confirmed?sub_confirmation=1";

// Testing code
foreach($testList as $key=>$val) {
    $l[] = new L($val);   
}

foreach($l as $key=>$val) {
    // Check for an error
    if ($val->error) {
        $val->debug();
    } else {
        echo '<pre>'.$val->getData().'</pre>';
    }
}
```

And the output would be:

```
object(L)#1 (3) {
  ["raw"]=>
  string(9) "test fail"
  ["modified"]=>
  NULL
  ["error"]=>
  bool(true)
}

https://youtube.com/searchFail
https://youtube.com/channel/success?sub_confirmation=1
https://youtube.com/channel/confirmed?sub_confirmation=1
```

Comment: this is a bit complicated for me, but I will try to understand and figure out what is important for me, still thank you :D